# Connection timeout on Sublime Text 3 SFTP

Tags: sublimetext3, sftp

I'm trying to map a local directory to a folder on my hosting provider, but I get a connection timeout error.

I've tried logging on from different ISP's, but I still get the same error. And I use these same credentials successfully in Filezilla.

Here is my config file:

```
{

// sftp, ftp or ftps
"type": "sftp",

"save_before_upload": true,
"upload_on_save": false,
"sync_down_on_open": false,
"sync_skip_deletes": false,
"sync_same_age": true,
"confirm_downloads": false,
"confirm_sync": true,
"confirm_overwrite_newer": false,

"host": "mydomain.com",
"user": "myusername",
"password": "mypassword",
// "port": "22",

"remote_path": "/",
"ignore_regexes": [
    "\\.sublime-(project|workspace)", "sftp-config(-alt\\d?)?\\.json",
    "sftp-settings\\.json", "/venv/", "\\.svn/", "\\.hg/", "\\.git/",
    "\\.bzr", "_darcs", "CVS", "\\.DS_Store", "Thumbs\\.db", "desktop\\.ini"
],
//"file_permissions": "664",
//"dir_permissions": "775",

//"extra_list_connections": 0,

"connect_timeout": 30,
//"keepalive": 120,
//"ftp_passive_mode": true,
//"ftp_obey_passive_host": false,
//"ssh_key_file": "~/.ssh/id_rsa",
//"sftp_flags": ["-F", "/path/to/ssh_config"],

//"preserve_modification_times": false,
//"remote_time_offset_in_hours": 0,
//"remote_encoding": "utf-8",
//"remote_locale": "C",
//"allow_config_upload": false,
}
```

Comment: I have a similar setup working OK; does the sublime console and/or the SFTP output panel have any information other than timeout error that might shed any light? The only thing that comes to mind would be either a network issue (doubtful since you can get it to work with FileZilla) or a slight typo in the host name that's making the IP resolve incorrectly.

Comment: yesterday, sublime text 3 sftp worked but today it don't work too me